# C# comparator sort by secondary value

Tags: c#, comparator, string-comparison

I'm using a comparator to sort a list of text. each list item contains plain text:

```
public class NameComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null) return 0;

            if (x == null || y == null) return -1;

            var parts1 = x.Split();
            var parts2 = y.Split();

            if (parts1.Length > 1 && parts2.Length > 1)
            {
                if (parts1[0] != parts2[0]) return parts1[0].CompareTo(parts2[0]);
                if (x.Contains("ptt") && y.Contains("ptt"))
                    return parts1[5].CompareTo(parts2[5]);
                else if (x.Contains("ptt"))
                    return parts1[5].CompareTo(parts2[11]);
                else if (y.Contains("ptt"))
                    return parts1[11].CompareTo(parts2[5]);
                else
                    return parts1[11].CompareTo(parts2[11]);
            }

            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

This comparators sorts just fine but i neeed a secondary sort.
for example 
instead of this:

```
-  2045< start FC  79812 
 - 2027< Slot 4  start FC  79812 
 - 2048< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2071< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2070< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2069< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2045< Slot 5  end FC  79812
 - 2051< Slot 5  end FC  79812
 - 2056< Slot 5  end FC  79812
```

i need it to sort like this:

```
-  2045< start FC  79812 
 - 2045< Slot 5  end FC  79812
 - 2027< Slot 4  start FC  79812 
 - 2048< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2071< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2070< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2069< Slot 4  start FC  79812
 - 2051< Slot 5  end FC  79812
 - 2056< Slot 5  end FC  79812
```

After the number after 'fc' I need to sort by the number before the '<'

Comment: You should only make a secondary comparison if the primary comparison IS zero, not if it is NOT zero, so your last sentence would appear to be incorrect.

Comment: Parsing strings on the fly is not very efficient since you are using split - which generates arrays of strings, please consider having a class that would represent the structure of your data, and have fileds for each part - then comparison algorithm would be much cleaner.

Comment: Primary/Secondary sorting is straightforward: (1) Compare primary keys. If that returns nonzero, return that value. (2) Otherwise return the result of comparing the secondary keys.